# WoL doesn't work

Tags: centos, wake-on-lan

I have two computers DELL OPTIPLEX 960 connected to one switch. Both have CentOs 7 with minimal installation.
IPs are 192.168.8.51/24 (MAC 00:26:b9:86:85:13) and 192.168.8.52/24 (MAC 00:26:b9:86:84:5f)

When I check `ip a` and I get enp0s25 (instead of typical eth0)

I have set

```
ethtool -s enp0s25 wol g
```

Now I run `shutdown` on IP 192.168.8.51

On 192.168.8.52 I run `ether-wake 00:26:b9:86:85:13`
and nothing happens.

When both computers are on, ping responds both directions.

EDIT: Wake-on Lan option in BIOS is ON

Comment: Please try `ether-wake -b 00:26:b9:86:85:13` and `ether-wake -P 9 00:26:b9:86:85:13` or `ether-wake -P9 00:26:b9:86:85:13`

Comment: Try enabling WOL in the bios

Comment: ether-wake -b 00:26:b9:86:85:13 - no effect, ether-wake -P 9 00:26:b9:86:85:13 and ether-wake -P9 00:26:b9:86:85:13 says invalid option 'P' '9'

Comment: also look for an "enable PME" option in the bios and try turning it on.

Comment: Apparently in some Dell bios' there is an option called Deep Sleep Control that needs to be disabled for WOL to work, if that option is in your BIOS give that a try

Comment: I have no deep sleep option in my BIOS. The same with PME. I cannot find anything like this. Should I shutdown the system with some specific parameter? I just use shutdown.

Comment: It worked.I have played a bit with different BIOS setting and it works. Almost... I can wake-up one computer from another but 1) I cannot wake it up using Windows tool https://www.depicus.com/wake-on-lan/wake-on-lan-cm 2) even if I manage to wake it up from CentOs, connected monitor is not waking-up. Any ideas?

Comment: Are both computers running the same bios version? And what version is it?